# TortoiseSVN error The XML response contains invalid XML and Malformed XML: no element found

Tags: xml, svn, tortoisesvn

My TortoiseSVN Checkout and Update error

**The XML response contains invalid XML
   Malformed XML: no element found**

What do you do
Please help me.

Comment: You are entering invalid repository URL.

Comment: For me this is being triggered by a zip file. If I try to export entire folder at once it fails, if I export each folder separately then it works.

Answer (score 19):

Most likely, you enter a web interface URL instead of SVN repository URL. You just need to copy the appropriate URL by clicking the **Checkout** button in the interface.

Read the article [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/) for the detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have fixed this problem using the option "Steal lock" (checkbox in bottom left area of the form when you are committing the files to the repository).

This error is caused because some files seem to be unlocked but really aren't. (Verify this from the Explorer window by clicking the properties of the file, then SVN Properties. Then you can see the real state of the file.)

Answer (score 1):

It can be some of your subdirectories under SVN version control mismatch with that of the remote.

1. Run `svn udpate` in subdirectories of your project, find out which one
   cause the problem.
2. Then run `svn up --set-depth empty && svn up --set-depth infinity` in that directory to cleanup and refetch all the files.

Answer (score 0):

old Q maybe the following ans will help someone

Cause
The error indicates that the **URL used to address the repository using Subversion client is inappropriate.**

Most likely, **the URL was copied from the web browser's address bar when exploring the repository through the web interface of VisualSVN Server.** Subversion client programs are not capable of handling the syntax of such URLs. The appropriate URLs should be obtained by clicking the Checkout button in the web interface.

Resolution
When you are going to check out a working copy or one way or another use a Subversion client to access a repository, **you should obtain the appropriate repository URL by clicking the Checkout button.**

Follow these steps to obtain the Subversion repository URL that can be used with a Subversion client program:

**On the VisualSVN Server web interface, navigate to the desired repository path.
Click the Checkout button at the top right-hand side of the web interface and copy the repository URL to clipboard.**

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the Apache web serves that serves my repository solved this problem for me. I found that the web server's error log contained messages such as:

```
[...] [error] [client a.b.c.d] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
[...] [error] [client a.b.c.d] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #185005]
[...] [error] [client a.b.c.d] Compression of svndiff data failed  [500, #185005]
```